# Losing context from JQuery post with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a JQuery dialog box on a page that calls something like this:

```
$.post("/MyController/MyAction", { myKey: key} //...
```

And this successfully gets here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(int myKey)
{
   //do some stuff
   return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction");       
}
```

The problem is that the RedirectToAction has no effect on the webbrowser. I am guessing this is because the JQuery post is kinda on a different 'tread' so it doesn't know where to send the response? How do I get the browser to load the new response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `$.post` is doing an ajax post and the Action will not redirect.

If you are reditecting anyway, why not just do a form submit, no need for ajax.

Alternatively you could do a `$.get` and return a JsonResult to indicate success/failure and redirect using jQuery/javascipt.

**Update**

Something like this:

Where you can set OK or ERR as a result and add any object as the "item" which can be something to use on the View or an error message, url to redirect to etc

```
[HttpPost] 
public JsonResult MyAction(int myKey) 
{ 
   //do some stuff 
   return new JsonResult { Data = new { Item = item, Result = "OK/ERR" } };
}
```