# MVC controller action launched from modal crashes losing jQuery context

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a problem that is similar to these two StackOverflow posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779340/mvc-partial-views-loses-track-of-the-images-folder-when-using-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707552/losing-context-from-jquery-post-with-asp-net-mvc). However my situation is just different enough that I'm not able to make the correction needed.

Like those two post I seem to be losing context as the browser does the post controller action.

The scenario is is follows:

1. Page Loads
2. User clicks add button.
3. Modal dialog loads partial view with fields needed to add new object.
4. Form is completed and user clicks save.
5. Controller action for add completes (add record just fine) then redirects to the controller action for step 1. The thought was this would close the modal and return user to page in step 1.

The problem is of course that the redirect results in a $ (jquery) is undefined error.

Step 1 controller action:

```
public ActionResult Configure()
{
  ....code...
  return View("~/FolderPath.../Configure.cshtml", model);
}
```

Step 2 jQuery to launch modal:

```
$("#new").click(function (e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   var window = $("#window").kendoWindow(
   {
      content: {
                 url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CreateEditRecord", "Controller"))",
                 data: { .... }
                }
            });
        window.data('kendoWindow').center();
});
```

Step 3 & 4 Modal submit:

```
$("#save").click(function (e)
{
   e.preventDefault();

   ...some validation stuff here.....

   $("#formCreateEditRecord").submit();
});
```

Step 5 (These are the different methods I have tried and they all lose jQuery context)

```
public ActionResult CreateEditRecord(NewRecordModel model)
{
    ...add new record to db etc.....

  //return RedirectToAction("Configure");

  //return Configure();

  //return PartialView("~/FolderPath/CreateEditRecord.cshtml", model);
  //tried this last one to return to modal window just trying to figure things out.


}
```

**Edit**

---

@SSA & @Ryios. Your explanations were very clear and do solve the problem but if you could bear with me a few seconds more....

I understand the partial view doesn't have the full weight (scripting tags etc.) of the full page. What I am still unclear of is WHY does it even go back to the partial view? My post controller action in step 5 redirects to configure action which is a full view so I would have expected the page to load the full view.

Does the MVC view engine still render the partial view even just for a few milliseconds before changing and reloading the full page again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 2 steps more,

1. Manually submit the form.
2. Return a JsonResult from action CreateEditRecord after a database operation.

//In controller action

```
  public JsonResult CreateEditRecord(NewRecordModel model)
  {
   // Do your database stuff here....
   //Then return Success or Failure based on your database result.
   return new JsonResult { Data = new { Result = "Success/Failure" } };
  }
```

Then when you call a submit form.

```
$("#save").click(function (e)
{
   e.preventDefault();

   ...some validation stuff here.....
    $("#formCreateEditRecord").submit(
    function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //As we will manually submit the form
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CreateEditRecord", "Controller"))",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
             //here we check if database called resulted in Success/Failure
             if(data.Result === "Success")
             {
              //Write your code to close the dialog.
             }else 
             {
              //Show error message or whatever.
             }
           }
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CreateEditRecord", "Controller"))"

That is rendering a partial view.  Partial views being what they are, typically don't have the full page weight, e.g. they don't have all your script tags.

When it loads as the content for the modal dialog it (itself) does not have jquery because you don't have script tags to load jQuery on the partial view.

So either, add jquery to your partial view, or refer to jQuery on the parent window.

```
"Note: I'm not sure if this next code stub will work or not as jQuery might be attached to the dom on the parent window and not find any elements on your Modal Window.  I know there is a way to do it though, you just might have to mess with your jQuery code a little bit.

$ = window.parent.$;
$("#save").click(function (e)
{
   e.preventDefault();

   ...some validation stuff here.....

   $("#formCreateEditRecord").submit();
});
```

With Ajax, partial views work because they are used to update portions of the original page.  However, with a modal dialog it's an entirely new page (in a sub window).

If you were using an InPage Modal Dialog solution like jQuery UI Dialogs, then you would have jquery available from your original page.

I suggest designing a base template for your partial views, something like

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="title">@this.ViewBag.ModalTitle</div>
    <div class="body">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
<!--Load Scripts/Styles Here-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", false)
```

Then you can create partial views that use it, like

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Partials/Dialogs/BaseDialog.cshtml";
}
<p>This is a test dialog</p>
@section scripts 
{
    <script src="anotherscripttoaddhere" />
}
```